# Deserialize JSON named property to .Net Object

Tags: .net, json, jsonserializer

The API I'm using provides a JSON payload. Part of the response has a property which contains an array of named objects. I think I want to deserialize this part into a .Net List, the problem is each object in the array is prepended with a name so I can't get it as a list.

Here's the payload:

```
{
  "ShipAction": "GetQuote",
  "Status": "Success",
  "RequestDate": "2012-02-08 21:18:19",
  "Username": "tpi",
  "QuoteID": "6M15AQOrCl059x",
  "QuoteExpires": "2012-02-22 21:18:20",
  "NoServices": 8,
  "DeliveryCountry": "France",
  "CheapestQuote": {
    "SubTotal": "15.96",
    "VatTotal": "3.19",
    "TotalPrice": "19.15"
  },
  "ServiceOptions": {
    "PF_INT": {
      "OptionID": "6183545",
      "Carrier": "PF_INT",
      "ServiceName": "Euro Priority",
      "AlternateName": false,
      "ServiceID": "PF_INT",
      "SubjectToVat": "Y",
      "SubTotal": "15.96",
      "VatTotal": "3.19",
      "TotalPrice": "19.15"
    },
    "FEDEX_ECON": {
      "OptionID": "6183549",
      "Carrier": "FEDEX",
      "ServiceName": "Economy Delivery",
      "AlternateName": false,
      "ServiceID": "FEDEX_ECON",
      "SubjectToVat": "Y",
      "SubTotal": "18.56",
      "VatTotal": "3.71",
      "TotalPrice": "22.27"
    },
    "FEDEX_PRI": {
      "OptionID": "6183548",
      "Carrier": "FEDEX",
      "ServiceName": "International Express",
      "AlternateName": false,
      "ServiceID": "FEDEX_PRI",
      "SubjectToVat": "Y",
      "SubTotal": "20.07",
      "VatTotal": "4.01",
      "TotalPrice": "24.08"
    },
    "TNT_EXPRESS": {
      "OptionID": "6183550",
      "Carrier": "TNT Export",
      "ServiceName": "TNT International Express",
      "AlternateName": false,
      "ServiceID": "TNT_EXPRESS",
      "SubjectToVat": "Y",
      "SubTotal": "20.73",
      "VatTotal": "4.15",
      "TotalPrice": "24.88"
    },
    "DHL_EURO": {
      "OptionID": "6183546",
      "Carrier": "DHL",
      "ServiceName": "DHL Euro Plus",
      "AlternateName": false,
      "ServiceID": "DHL_EURO",
      "SubjectToVat": "Y",
      "SubTotal": "23.10",
      "VatTotal": "4.62",
      "TotalPrice": "27.72"
    },
    "TNT_ECONOMY": {
      "OptionID": "6183551",
      "Carrier": "TNT Export",
      "ServiceName": "TNT International Economy Express",
      "AlternateName": false,
      "ServiceID": "TNT_ECONOMY",
      "SubjectToVat": "Y",
      "SubTotal": "24.14",
      "VatTotal": "4.83",
      "TotalPrice": "28.97"
    },
    "DHL_INT": {
      "OptionID": "6183547",
      "Carrier": "DHL TD",
      "ServiceName": "Time Definite",
      "AlternateName": false,
      "ServiceID": "DHL_INT",
      "SubjectToVat": "Y",
      "SubTotal": "30.79",
      "VatTotal": "6.16",
      "TotalPrice": "36.95"
    },
    "PALLETWAYS_EURO_QUAR": {
      "OptionID": "6183552",
      "Carrier": "PALLETWAYS_EURO",
      "ServiceName": "Quarter Pallet Delivery",
      "AlternateName": false,
      "ServiceID": "PALLETWAYS_EURO_QUAR",
      "SubjectToVat": "Y",
      "SubTotal": "152.67",
      "VatTotal": "30.53",
      "TotalPrice": "183.20"
    }
  }
}
```

I want a list of 'ServiceOptions'.. I would be happy to use Json.Net to do this, but again I'm stumped..

Comment: @Etienne de martel, how did you format the JSON, I struggled but failed?

Comment: Like any code: just indent each line with 4 spaces (or, better yet, select the whole code and press the "code" button). For more information, read the [Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an "array of named objects" as you called it is a well-know data structure and is called **dictionary** or **map**. (For .NET see [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).)

Just use `Dictionary<string, YourServiceOptionObject>` for `ServiceOptions` property.

Side note: in fact the structure of the property `ServiceOptions`, which you probably refer to, differs in no way from `CheapestQuote` property, apart from the fact that each *key* instead of primitive value posses the value which is another nested dictionary/object.

Comment: Couldn't see the wood from the trees.. Thank you!